# How to add the Organic Group list in the user profile

Tags: organic-groups

Is there a way to add the Organic Group list in the user profile

The OG List appear in the Registration Form but not in the user profile

Not appear in this path 
/user/[uid]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is slightly vague, however, I am going to answer in the two methods that I take away from it.

1. You want a list of all OG groups on a user page: Create a View for all of the different content you have related to groups (i.e. you have a content type called "Groups" that is an Organic Group).
2. You want a list of all OG groups that a user is a member of: Create a View (with a contextual link and/or relationship) between the UID in the current URL and get their appropriate group memberships.

You can create either of these Views as a block and place that on the /user page.